USD support in blender 4.2.1?
Has anyone else been testing or using USD with Blender 4.2.1? I've just started testing with Blender 4.2 LTS with little success. But I have had success with the 4.2 alpha branch in the Omniverse launcher.
In the alpha branch I was able to get the umm material mapper to remap my omnishaders.
However in the 4.2 LTS documentation it mentions preview surfaces from USD import should work but I have had no luck with that.
Has anyone had any success with USD in 4.2.1 LTS
